# TextView not sending ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS_CLEARED event

Tags: android, accessibility, uiaccessibility

I want to catch the event when the textView looses the Accessibility focus. i.e. when the user swipes and moves to the next view.

I have set up an Accessibility delegate on the textView and overrode

```
@Override
  public void sendAccessibilityEvent(View host, int eventType) {
       switch (eventType) {
             case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUSED:
                  break;
             case AccessibilityEvent.TYPE_VIEW_ACCESSIBILITY_FOCUS_CLEARED:
                  break;
            }
}
```

But I never get the accessibility focus clear event. Any pointers? 
This textView is defined in an XML like the following

```
<LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_image"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv_text"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:importantForAccessibility="yes"/>
</LinearLayout>
```